# What behavior would I see if I connect a dimmable LED fixture to a fluorescent ballast?

Tags: electrical, ballast

I want to replace a fluorescent fixture with a dimmable LED fixture (standard LED, not fluorescent-replacement). I suspect the legacy ballast is hidden behind the drywall in the ceiling, but it's possible that it was removed.

When I wire up the LED fixture, it turns on incredibly dimly. I measure 90V between hot and neutral. Is this consistent with accidentally still having a ballast in the circuit?

UPDATE: There was a loose neutral upstream of the fixture. (The ballast was also confirmed to have been removed.)

Comment: Can you provide some pictures of the junction box?

Comment: Usually the ballast is inside of the fixture under the tubes.  It is also against code to have electric connections hidden behind drywall.  90v is usually due to loose/dirty connections or a bleeding off voltage to ground/neutral.

Comment: Were the wires you attached to black-white or black-white-bare/green?  If so, I would say your choice was reasonable and the problem lies elsewhere. Also I'd do a postmortem on the fluorescent fixture to see if the ballast can be definitively found. Otherwise I would strongly admonish you to stop experimenting, because "experimenting" will yield many combinations which will apparently work, *and then kill you*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Good point. Black/white/bare.

Comment: The problem has been resolved. Question updated.